# Proof verification: $\frac{a}{(bc-a^2)^2}+\frac{b}{(ca-b^2)^2}+\frac{c}{(ab-c^2)^2}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

The question states:

> Let $a, b, c$ be real numbers such that $$\frac{1}{(bc-a^2)}+\frac{1}{(ca-b^2)}+\frac{1}{(ab-c^2)}=0$$ Prove that $$\frac{a}{(bc-a^2)^2}+\frac{b}{(ca-b^2)^2}+\frac{c}{(ab-c^2)^2}=0$$

Now this can be solved with algebraic manipulation, but I want to check if my solution is valid too:

By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$\left (\frac{a^2}{(bc-a^2)^3}+\frac{b^2}{(ca-b^2)^3}+\frac{c^2}{(ab-c^2)^3}\right )\left (\frac{1}{(bc-a^2)}+\frac{1}{(ca-b^2)}+\frac{1}{(ab-c^2)}\right ) \ge \left (\frac{a}{(bc-a^2)^2}+\frac{b}{(ca-b^2)^2}+\frac{c}{(ab-c^2)^2}\right )^2 = P^2$$
Hence, $0 \ge P^2 \implies P = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C-S it's the following:
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\right)^2$$ for any reals $a_i$ and $b_i$,

which says that your solution is wrong because $bc-a^2$ may be negative and can not be square of real number.  You can not use C-S so.

By the way, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{ab-c^2}=\frac{(ab+ac+bc)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-bc)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2-bc)}$$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(bc-a^2)^2}=\frac{(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-bc)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b^2-a^2bc)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2-bc)^2},$$ which gives the solution.

Comment: i appreciate your solution, but what i wanted was a verification of my attempt.

Comment: @asdf256 I added something. See now.

Comment: why can't i use C-S? isn't it defined over all real numbers? am i missing something obvious?

Comment: oh, that makes a lot more sense. thanks for the clarification. is there any way i could prove this using inequalities?

Comment: @asdf256 Yes, because if $bc-a^2<0$, so it can not be square of a real number.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not valid, and by coincidence, you don't arrive at an obvious contradiction because the final answer is zero too.
Let's examine a numerical example.

For $a=1, b=1, c=\frac{-1}{2}$, we get $\frac {1}{bc-a^2}+\frac {1}{ca-b^2}+\frac {1}{ab-c^2}=0$. If your approach was supposed to be correct, in a similar way, we would get:

$$(a^2(bc-a^2)+b^2(ac-b^2)+c^2(ab-c^2))(\frac {1}{bc-a^2}+\frac {1}{ca-b^2}+\frac {1}{ab-c^2})\ge (a+b+c)^2,$$

therefore we would have $a+b+c=0$, which is impossible according to the set of $a=1, b=1, c=\frac{-1}{2}$.

Indeed, the correct inequality we are allowed to use is:
$$(|(a^2(bc-a^2)|+|b^2(ac-b^2)|+|c^2(ab-c^2)|)(|\frac {1}{bc-a^2}|+|\frac {1}{ca-b^2}|+|\frac {1}{ab-c^2}|)\ge (a+b+c)^2,$$

and the same goes for the inequality you used (considering the absolute values).

Similar to Michael Rozenberg's solution, you can see [this link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1065429p4626867).